# Navigate the user to another URL using useNavigate() of react-router-dom-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a React 18 application and I am trying to navigate the guest user to the shipping page (URL: `localhost:3000/shipping`) from the cart page by clicking the **Proceed to Checkout** button. On clicking the button, the user should be first re-directed to the sign in page where he should sign in (on the `SigninScreen` page) and then proceed to the shipping page.

The current url when clicking the **Proceed to Checkout** button is (URL: `localhost:3000/signin?redirect=shipping`)

On clicking the `SignIn` button on the `SignInScreen` page I do a redirect in the `useEffect()` hook:

```
import { useSearchParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
const { userInfo, loading, error } = userSignin;

const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const redirectUrl = searchParams.get('redirect') || '/';

const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  // If the user is logged in, the user should redirected to the shipping page.
  if (userInfo) {
    navigate(redirectUrl, {replace: true});
  }
}, [userInfo, redirectUrl, navigate]);
```

Even after using `{replace: true}` the user does not get navigated to `localhost:3000/shipping`, instead it gets redirected to `localhost:3000/signin/shipping`

Could someone please guide me on what am I doing wrong?

Tried: Even after using `{replace: true}` the user does not get navigated to `localhost:3000/shipping`, instead it gets redirected to `localhost:3000/signin/shipping`

Expectation: The user should navigate to `localhost:3000/shipping` from `localhost:3000/signin?redirect=shipping` on signing the user in on the sign in screen by clicking the Sign In button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs which do not start with a `/` are treated as relative links to the current route.  You are navigating the user to `shipping` when it should be `/shipping`.

Here’s one way to add the starting slash:

```
const redirectUrl = '/' + (searchParams.get('redirect') || '');
```